# How to update a Github project on IntellijIdea

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea

Everyone

I don't know if the question has already been asked, but I'm looking everywhere but I can't find it.
I am working on a project on Intellij IDEA using GitHub.
I use my desktop computer at work to develop. After finishing I make a commit on Github and it is directly on my account.
But, sometimes I would like to continue at home on my laptop, using the same project as well as modifying and committing it.
Not knowing much about Github in integration with Intellij, I know that I can take an existing project and thus download it locally on my computer. But my question is, how can I update the changed files on each computer.
Example, I work at the office, I modified the A and B file, I commit it to Github, and at home on my computer, I update the Github project on Intellij and suddenly I have the new files modified.

If you have a solution, thank you!

Comment: you mean to ask: how do I execute a git pull?

Comment: You commit or you also push? Because if you just commit, your changes never reach the remote repository. If you push, then why you can't just pull?

Comment: This is really not about Github per se. This is just simple work with a git repository, no matter where it's located. You clone the project once to your home machine, you work, commit, and then push. In the other machine, pull before continuing to work. Consult with your team about creating your own branch or whatever.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. as explained, you need to pull. The "best" command in AndroidStudio / IntelliJ for this is to "update project" which I believe maps by default to CMD T on macOS and control T elsewhere. It's in the `git` menu. This will likely perform a merge since it will need to merge your local changes with whatever was pushed from another computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should need to take a "deeper" look into git fundamentals, here's a quick tutorial I think would do for your case:
[Learn the Basics of Git in Under 10 Minutes](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-the-basics-of-git-in-under-10-minutes-da548267cc91/)

Also (if u can, and have the time) I would suggest you learn to use the git CLI before the IntelliJIDEA integrated plugin, so that, in case of problems, you know where to look under the hood.

To put it in easy words the most straight-forward thing you can do is (assuming you have already set-up a repo and a branch to work on):

(on the device you just worked on)

1. `git commit -am "comment your wip here"`
2. `git push`

(on the device where you want to get the work updated)

1. `git pull`

Comment: I know the basics of Git, but it's not complicated. So, if I understand the tutorial, for my problem, I have to use Git Fetch?

Comment: Git fetch retieves the branches. I think you want git pull, as stated in a couple prior comments above.

Comment: You think is working ? @JWoodchuck

Comment: But since you mention IntelliJ, are you asking how to execute a git pull from within IntelliJ?

Comment: @JWoodchuck My question is simple, is how from Intellij I can "update" my Intellij project on each computer via my Github project?
If I do a git pull on Intellij, will it update the project every time on each computer?

Comment: So you mean some kind of “push” from GitHub to any/all various locally checked out instances of the repo?

Comment: yes that's it normally, every time I connect to one of my computers, I update the project via github to get the new files and the modified files

Comment: That's exactly why I mentioned you should check before how git works and how you should setup and use repositories, branches and so on in an appropriate and correct way. (Using the intellij integrated plugin is no evil, but I guess you should at least know how it works, there is also the GUI for git that may help you!). At first it could look kinda tricky or weird but trust me, once you go git, you'll never rollback!